# Autoencoder using MLP for anomaly detection in multivariate timeseries

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am developing an autoencoder using an MLP to detect anomalies in a multivariate time series. To simplify the problem, I started using only one series variable.

**Univariate case**

The way I'm applying it is to break the time series into pieces, and present those pieces to the network. For example, my series consists of 1000 points, which I break into 50 subseries of length 20. Each of these subseries becomes an example for learning the network.

What should the DAE `input_shape` be? I saw that there is a difference if `shape=(20, )` and `shape=(20,1)`. I leave below the code of the DAE that I have been working on. And how should the format of the last layer of the DAE be? When I use the output layer with only 1 neuron, the model works correctly, why?

```
model = keras.Sequential([

        ### ENCODING ###
        layers.Input(shape=(df_train.shape[1], df_train.shape[2])),
       # or ?
       #layers.Input(shape=(df_train.shape[1],)),

        layers.Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.1),                     
        layers.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'),

        ### LATENT SPACE
        layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'),

        ### DECODING ###
        layers.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'),
        layers.Dropout(rate=0.1),               
        layers.Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'),
     
        layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

])
```

**Multivariate case**

Considering the multivariate case, in which I have 16 time series. How would the input shape and output layer look?

Answer (score 0):

Dense layers, the building block of an MPL, only take a single dimension. So you must flatten your 2D vector into 1D. The shape of the vector will `(width*height,)`.

The alternative is to use a Convolutional or Recurrent Autoencoder (LSTM/GRU). With a convolutional autoencoder, most of the layers will be either Conv2d or Conv1d. Then you would use a single Dense layer as the compressive bottleneck. Convolutional layers take inputs on shape (width,height,channel) - where channel can be 1 if there is no third dimension.